# passing an id in session in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to pass an id to a session: I am trying to do the following in my view:

```
$editThisUser = array(
    'editThisUser' => $user['id']
);

$this->session->set_userdata($editThisUser);
```

and I am trying to read this data in my controler like this:

```
$editWhat = $this->session->userdata('editThisUser');
echo $editWhat;
```

I am getting wrong user id, all the time. I guess that this is happening because I am using the userdata to track if the user is logged in:

Here is what I have in my controller, which checks user credential:

```
$data = array(
    'username'       => $this->input->post('username'),
    'isUserLoggedIn' => true
);    
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

And now, whenever I try to read the

```
$editWhat = $this->session->userdata('editThisUser');
echo $editWhat;
```

I am getting the id of the logged user??!!!

Anyone can help??

EDIT>
I will post whole code tomorrow, I guess I did not explain well what I am trying to achieve.

Regards, Zoran

Comment: What "wrong id" do you get? 0? Random integer? Also, did you load the session library?

Comment: I get an id of already logged user. It is back office,and I am trying to edit the users. I didn't want to pass the user id with a get, and I am trying to add the user id to the session variable. I guess that problem is because I already use the session to track which user is logged in

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: You joined two tables in your query, and got the id of the wrong table? Sorry, need more info to give better advice...

```
//Trying these might help you pinpoint the source of the problem
var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());
var_dump($whatever_result_set_contains_your_user_info);
```

This will display all the userdata of your session in great detail, so you will be able to see if your userdata is updated properly. Will check for more info tommorow :)

Comment: No. It is back office where I log in, and session is tracking my username, and if I am logged in. Now, I am listing all users, and I have edit option. There, I am trying to pass all users id, and I want to add the user id to a session variable. It works, but I always get the logged user id, instead of the user that I am trying to edit.